# Removing gnome-screensaver also wants to remove gnome-core

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I am on Ubuntu 11.10.  I hope to be able to replace gnome-screensaver with xscreensaver.  I have read instructions on many sites that one simply uninstalls gnome-screensaver and then installs xscreensaver.

However, when I request removing gnome-screensaver, the system wants to remove much more than just the gnome-screensaver.

```
TheGeeko61> sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome gnome-core gnome-screensaver
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 483 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

(Surely they cannot collectively add up to only 483 kB.)  Must I really remove gnome and gnome-core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not really need to remove gnome-screensaver , disable gnome-screensaver (and enable xscreensaver) in `gnome-session-properties`

[image]

If you really wish to remove it you may as gnome and gnome-core are meta packages, similar to ubuntu-desktop. meta packages are a list of packages to be installed.

See [Ubuntu Wiki Metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) for details

Comment: Yes, I have done that (disabled gnome-screensaver and enabled xscreensaver).  However, after rebooting and logging in, gnome-screensaver has been started!  Although gnome-session-properties reports that it is disabled.

Comment: I will continue with the 2nd approach...  don't seem to have a choice.  It's comforting to know that those metapackages are not the real deal.

Comment: Beautiful.  The 2nd approach did work without a flaw.  Thank you for steering me towards the article on meta packages.

Comment: you are most welcome, glad it worked for you